# GroupBy a dataframe records and display all columns with PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

I have the following dataframe

```
dataframe - columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnE
```

I want to groupBy columnC and then consider max value of columnE

```
dataframe .select('*').groupBy('columnC').max('columnE')
```

**expected output**

```
dataframe - columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnE
```

**Real output**

```
dataframe - columnC, columnE
```

Why all columns in the dataframe are not displayed as expected ?

Comment: Why would you expect all the columns to be displayed when you only aggregated the data for one column in each group?

Comment: @It_is_Chris because as per my understanding groupBy and aggregate max() function behave same as MYSQL. I want to group data by columnC and then out of that result want to get rows with max colunE

Answer (score 1):

For Spark version >= 3.0.0 you can use [max_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#max_by) to select the additional columns.

```python
import random
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

#create some testdata
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [[random.randint(1,3)] + random.sample(range(0, 30), 4)  for _ in range(10)], 
  schema=["columnC", "columnB", "columnA", "columnD", "columnE"]) \
  .select("columnA", "columnB", "columnC", "columnD", "columnE")

df.groupBy("columnC") \
  .agg(F.max("columnE"), 
      F.expr("max_by(columnA, columnE) as columnA"),
      F.expr("max_by(columnB, columnE) as columnB"),
      F.expr("max_by(columnD, columnE) as columnD")) \
  .show()
```

For the testdata

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|columnA|columnB|columnC|columnD|columnE|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     25|     20|      2|      0|      2|
|     14|      2|      2|     24|      6|
|     26|     13|      3|      2|      1|
|      5|     24|      3|     19|     17|
|     22|      5|      3|     14|     21|
|     24|      5|      1|      8|      4|
|      7|     22|      3|     16|     20|
|      6|     17|      1|      5|      7|
|     24|     22|      2|      8|      3|
|      4|     14|      1|     16|     11|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

the result is

```
+-------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|columnC|max(columnE)|columnA|columnB|columnD|
+-------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1|          11|      4|     14|     16|
|      3|          21|     22|      5|     14|
|      2|           6|     14|      2|     24|
+-------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Even if columnA, columnB, columnD have string values this way can be used right?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be done via WINDOW function. Not groupBy

- partition your data by columnC
- Order your data within each partition in desc  (rank)
- filter out your desired result.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("columnC").orderBy(col("columnE").desc())

expectedDf = df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)) \
    .filter(col("rank") == 1)
```

You might wanna restructure your question.